# Escaping double quotes inside backticks

Tags: kotlin

Is there a way to use double quotes in a method name, like this?

```
@Test
fun `should do "something"`() {
    // ...
}
```

It works with `'`, but not with `"`. Is there a way to escape double quotes?

(I'm getting a compilation error due to incorrect syntax)

Answer (score 2):

Special characters can be used in method names if escaped with back-ticks. 
Your example compiles in my Kotlin project. 
But it also depends on the target platform, if compiling to the Android then the set of characters is more restrictive.

See discussion here - https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/more-characters-allowed-for-identifiers-than-grammar-specifies-what-is-supported/2359/11

And the grammar definition here - https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/grammar.html#Identifier

Comment: are you sure about the "special characters can be used in method names if escaped with back-ticks"?

Comment: @LiorH I'm working with JDK 11, which version are you using?

Comment: I'm running with JDK 8 and Kotlin 1.3.31. @Roland I'm not sure, but that's what I understood from the attached thread. It also compiled and ran successfully as a test.

Comment: which special characters need to (or can) be escaped with back-ticks? I can't escape anything with it (1.3.41).

Comment: @Roland It's the entire name which is "escaped with back-ticks", not separate characters.

Comment: @AlexeyRomanov ah, ok... for me it read like there is an additional possibility to escape special characters within the back-tick-escaped function name... thanks for the clarification...